# Implementing timer Javascript - Trivia Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written up a Trivia Game in Javascript, but am having a hard time understanding how to correctly implement a timer for each question. I've made it so that each question gets presented individually, and I'd like to have a timer for each question. If the timer runs out, it should proceed to the next question.

Here is a `link` to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyhkv7e4/)

If someone could take a few minutes and modify the JSFiddle, or let me know what I'd have to do in order to make each question count down from 10, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Putting code tags like `link` to get around not posting any code with a fiddle is not what you are supposed to do. You should post your code here, because if for some reason `JSFiddle` goes down this question is useless to the community. Also, we are not here to review your code. If you have an issue or a challenge post some code where you have attempted the problem at hand.

Comment: what you want is setTimeOut() nad/or setInterval(). http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Thanks, @RAEC, I appreciate the links and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers in JavaScript work asynchronously. This is the first thing you should know. Secondly depending on what you need you can use either a:

- `setTimeout(function, timeout)` This one allows you to delay an execution of a function provided by a time provided (in milliseconds).
- `setInterval(function, timer)` This one makes the function call every `timer` milliseconds

Depending on how you intertwine these your code should do something like:

```
function timerExpired(){
  questionCounter++;
  newQuestion();
  setTimeout(timerExpired, 15000);
}
//This one will make sure that every 15 seconds, your questions get "moved on" to the next question. You can do the same with an interval, like so:
setInterval(function(){
  questionCounter++;
  newQuestion();
}, 15000);
```

This is as far as I can go without this turning into me writting your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Dellirium, that should get me somewhere! I'll let you know should I have another Q.